# Convert BLOB into an image and display it (ReactJS)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, axios, blob

A MySQL database is holding user images and I want to query it for the image and display it on a navbar. Here is my navbar component that uses `axios.post` to make a request to my server. I tried converting the blob into an image and storing it in a variable, but I'm not sure why `img.onload` never fires.

```
export default function Navbar() {
    const isAuth = window.localStorage.getItem('isAuth');
    const [img1, setImg1] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/nav', {id: isAuth})
            .then((response) => {
                const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = url;
                img.onload = () => {
                    console.log("Image Loaded");
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(blob.type);
                    setImg1(dataURL);
                };
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [isAuth]);

    return (...)
}
```

My server side code queries the database and returns a blob if it exists.

```
app.post('/nav', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    db.query("SELECT img1 FROM users WHERE id = ? ", id, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        if (result.length === 0)
            res.json({ data: 'false' });
        else
            res.json({ data: result[0].img1 });
    })
})
```

Is there a disconnect of information somewhere between the client and server? Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the URL created by `createObjectURL` directly as the image source. Another thing if blob is returned from server you can set `responseType` to "blob" in axios config.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/nav', {
                id: isAuth
            }, {
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
            .then((response) => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
                setImg1(url);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [isAuth]);

<img src={img1} alt="Image" />
```